# How are errors handled when combining publishers?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have started using Combine quite recently and I am trying to create a repository that returns the combination of several data sources. To do that, each data source loads its own data in a quite simple load method:

```
func loadData() -> AnyPublisher<DataObject, Error>
```

To combine the data sources I thought of using `combineLatest`, since it'll wait for the data sources to finish loading and then it'll publish either a combined set with the data or an error indicating that it failed:

```
func loadData() -> AnyPublisher<[DataObject], Error> {
   return dataSource1.loadData()
             .combineLatest(dataSource2.loadData())
             .map { $0.0 + $0.1 }
             .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Overall the behavior of it seems alright, I can call `repository.loadData()` and I'll get an array that includes the data for both items. However, that's not the case if any of the data sources fail. In that case, the load method will return an error regardless of whether the other data source succeeded.

Is there a standard or recommended way to collect all the errors when combining publishers? In my use context I'd like to be able to discard the error only if both publishers failed, but go through and succeed if only one of them does.

Comment: `combineLatest` doesn't give you an array - it gives a tuple of the latest value from the first data source and the latest from the second, so your `loadData` example is wrong

Comment: To clarify, you want to ignore errors unless both upstream publishers failed, but to continue emitting values if only one failed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I edited the example so it includes an array, it was just to showcase the problem of the errors.

Comment: Your edit still won't work, unless you have a custom `+` function that creates an array of two `DataObject` objects.. maybe you meant `.map { [$0.0, $0.1] }`? But in any case, what value would you emit if one failed? Or are you looking for a [`Merge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/merge(with:)-9r2dw) behavior? That wouldn't give you an array - it would interleave values from each publisher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you're saying you want this:

1. If `dataSource1` fails and `dataSource2` produces output, discard the failure from `dataSource1` and pass along just the output from `dataSource2`.
2. If `dataSource1` produces output and `dataSource2` fails, pass along just the output from `dataSource1` and discard the failure from `dataSource2`.
3. If both `dataSource1` and `dataSource2` produce output, pass along the combined outputs.
4. If both `dataSource1` and `dataSource2` fail, pass along one of the errors.

I assume each data source produces at most one output. Here's a test setup:

```
typealias DataObject = String

struct DataSource {
    var result: Result<DataObject, Error>

    func loadData() -> AnyPublisher<DataObject, Error> {
        return result.publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

We do want to use `combineLatest`, but we can't let either input to `combineLatest` fail, because that will make `combineLatest` fail. We only want `combineLatest` to fail if **both** data sources fail. So we need a way to pass a error into `combineLatest` as an **output** of one of its input publishers, instead of as a **failure** of one of its input publishers.

We do that by transforming each input publisher to have an `Output` of `Result<DataObject, Error>` and a `Failure` of `Never`.

```
func combine(
    _ source1: DataSource,
    _ source2: DataSource
) -> AnyPublisher<[DataObject], Error> {
    let ds1 = source1.loadData()
        .map { Result.success($0) }
        .catch { Just(Result.failure($0)) }

    let ds2 = source2.loadData()
        .map { Result.success($0) }
        .catch { Just(Result.failure($0)) }

    let combo = ds1.combineLatest(ds2)
        .tryMap { r1, r2 -> [DataObject] in
            switch (r1, r2) {
            case (.success(let s1), .success(let s2)): return [s1, s2]
            case (.success(let s1), .failure(_)): return [s1]
            case (.failure(_), .success(let s2)): return [s2]
            case (.failure(let f1), .failure(_)): throw f1
            }
        }

    return combo.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Let's test it:

```
struct MockError: Error { }

combine(.init(result: .success("hello")), .init(result: .success("world")))
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
// Output:
// ["hello", "world"]
// finished

combine(.init(result: .success("hello")), .init(result: .failure(MockError())))
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
// Output:
// ["hello"]
// finished

combine(.init(result: .failure(MockError())), .init(result: .success("world")))
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
// Output:
// ["world"]
// finished

combine(.init(result: .failure(MockError())), .init(result: .failure(MockError())))
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
// Output:
// failure(__lldb_expr_28.MockError())
```

Comment: This was a fantastic solution and it works great, thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent explanation of a very useful case, thank you!